# How to localise VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, localization, vscode-extensions

I wrote a VS Code extension to support printing. Since all the recent issues have been concerned with issues relating to foreign character sets, it seems like I should support languages other than English.

But I can't find anything in on localisation in the VS Code API documentation. There's a section on languages but that's about parsing and syntax colouring etc for computer languages.

Is there any support or at least convention regarding localisation of VS Code extensions?

---

Thanks to Gama11 for pointing me at good resources.

Comment: I believe this is not possibel. VScode itself also doesn't come localized.

Comment: Of course VSCode is localized. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales

Comment: I learned something new. Thanks for pointing me (us) in the right direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and there is actually a I18n sample extension for this:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/l10n-sample

It's best if you read the readme, but the basic idea is the following:

- use the [`vscode-nls-dev`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-nls-dev) NPM package
- use NLS identifiers such as `"%extension.sayHello.title%"` as placeholders for command titles and such in `package.json`
- similarly, in JS code NLS identifiers can be translated with a `localize()` method imported from `vscode-nls`
- have a toplevel `i18n` directory that contains the translations for those identifiers for the languages that are supported in `<file-name>.i18n.json` files

---

Alternatively, you could also take a look at how the C++ extension does it:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/tree/main/Extension

They seem to take a slightly different approach: no `i18n` directory, but instead have the translations directly next to the file (`package.nls.it.json`, `package.nls.zh-cn.json` and `package.nls.json` with the default / English). I'm not sure if it translates anything outside of `package.json` / in JS code though.

Comment: This is at least part of what I seek. I have two commands, and this will definitely help with those. I haven't had time for a thorough look, but perhaps you can say: will this also allow translations of setting names and descriptions?

Comment: I'm not sure about setting names, but I think setting descriptions should be possible.

Comment: I've had another quick look and on the face of it both settings and descriptions can be localised, so I'm taking this as an answer.

Comment: The link of i18n-sample code has been modified to the following url

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/l10n-sample

Answer (score 2):

The official l10n (localization) sample extension should help a lot, as the old i18n (internationalization) sample has been deprecated.

Clone it here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/l10n-sample

Comment: It's not only the sample that's changed. The reason for the change is a new API supporting localisation of strings within the extension, which was promoted to a release version quite recently. The sample has been updated in support of this. A CLI toolchain is also being considered to support the _ongoing_ process of string extraction, replacement with tokens and managing translation to multiple target languages, although this is not publicly available yet.

Comment: @PeterWone Thanks for the info! Where did you get the message and where to track more?