# To what does the first parameter of NLS localize refer?

Tags: typescript, localization, vscode-extensions

Apropos of [How to localise VSCode extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420338/how-to-localise-vscode-extension/56424335#56424335) I would also like to know why the localize function requires *two* parameters.

Localising settings is straightforward; you replace literal values with tokens surrounded by percent signs and the token is replaced using a dictionary from a file, the file being determined by the current locale.

But the `localize` function requires *at least two* parameters, a `key` and a `message`. It can take an arbitrary number of subsequent parameters of any type, helpfully characterised as "args".

The documentation for this is close to non-existent.

Out of the box the sample won't even compile until you modify the `package.json` for a minimum vscode version of 1.34 up from 1.32 to accommodate updates to the TS typing files. Once you sort that out the sample compiles and launches but doesn't seem to work (activate doesn't run, I'm still figuring out why).

It does contain an example call to localize but the key it uses is "sayHello.text" and I can't find a corresponding string in the localisation resources. The arbitrary `args` business suggests runtime composition but this is not demonstrated in the sample. I can't really fault the documentation because there isn't any.

Can anyone explain the parameters?

Having a rummage in the vscode-nls repo I found this.

```
export function localize(_key: string | LocalizeInfo, message: string, ...args: any[]): string {
    return format(message, args);
}
```

By all appearances it doesn't even *use* `_key` but there is a `localizeFunc` with a similar signature that *does* use it, and I suspect a call to the config function performs some chicanery with names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config function does indeed do weird magic. It's a superb example of the vast gulf between clever and smart. And it makes webpack even more of a joy than usual.

Suppose you decide to support French.

In your project's `i18n` folder you create a folder `fra`. Yes, *three* letters. There's a standard for three letter country codes. Bing is your friend.

You probably already know to put a `package.i18n.json` file in it and fill that with name value pairs like so

```json
{
    "extension.sayHello.title": "Bonjour",
    "extension.sayBye.title": "Au revoir"
}
```

and the values will be substituted for package.json values of the same form bounded with percent signs.

If you create an `out` folder sibling to `packages.i18n.json` and put `extension.i18n.json` in the `out` folder containing this

```json
{
    "sayHello.text": "Bonjour d'extension.i18n.json"
}
```

then the value you should pass for `_key` is "sayHello.text". The second parameter is a fallback value for when localisation fails to find an entry corresponding to the key you supplied *for the current display language*.

Before all this can work you have three more things to do.

1. Edit `gulpfile.js` to register the languages you're supporting.

   ```js
   const languages = [
    { folderName: 'jpn', id: 'ja' },
    { folderName: 'fra', id: 'fr' }
   ];
   ```
2. Install gulp and run `gulp build`
3. Set your display language to French.

`localize("sayHello.text", "default value")` will then return "Bonjour d'extension.i18n.json" when the display language is set to French and "default value" for all other display languages.

The optional arguments can allegedly replace tokens in the return value but documentation for this is dismal and I've never seen it used.

**Note** If you have imports of classes defined in nested folders you have to match the folder hierarchy with the folder hierarchy you use for the localising dictionaries. If you *aren't* building into an `out` folder you probably need to adjust that too.

There's a [minimal worked example from Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/i18n-sample). It has bugger all explanation but if you use this answer as a guide to interpreting the sample you'll be well away.